# Renaming/appending Multiple file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have over 250 files in a directory each with a unique name. I have to add **.csv** at the end of each file. I tried writing a code for that in Python.

```
import os

path = "directory location"

files = os.listdir(path)
   
for index, file in enumerate(files):
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, ''.join('.csv')))
```

I don't want to give them a serial number or any other name as I want to keep the original name of the file and I don't want to do the manually rename all of the files.

Comment: Replace os.path.join(path, ''.join('.csv')) with os.path.join(path, file+'.csv')

Answer (score 0):

in os.rename api call, destination string is not placed correctly, its missing file name (file).  os.path.join(path, ''.join('.csv')) >> os.path.join(path, file+ ''.join('.csv')) or just file +".cvs"